# mvc entity framework select with dynamic where clause

Tags: entity-framework, select, union

I am doing a [asp.net-mvc](/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc) with [entity-framework](/questions/tagged/entity-framework) App.

I have a `select` instruction, where I need to have a dymanic `where` condition.

It is a common case where you have a filter composed by a string like "aaaa bbbb cccc". I need to bring all data that contains all the filter string or part of it.

I doing part ot it witt `Split` function, but it is difficult to get all posible combinations.

I Would rather use a `Store Procedure`. But the porpose of it, is to use Entity Framework.

As far I did this.

```html
 public IEnumerable<UploadSearch> GetUploadsBySearch(string search)
        {
            IEnumerable<UploadSearch> viewModel = (from uploads in _db.Uploads
                                                   .Where(p => p.ProcessState_id == Security.APPROVED && p.Finder.Contains(search))
                                                   .OrderByDescending(p => p.UploadDate)
                                                   select new UploadSearch
                                                   {
                                                       User_id = uploads.User_id,
                                                       UserName = uploads.Users.Name,
                                                       UserLastName = uploads.Users.LastName,
                                                   });
```

And I Add a for instruction to `loop` throu the string,

```html
 string[] param = search.Replace("  "," ").Split(' ');
            string _param = "";
             int large = param.Length; 

for (int i=0;i<large-1;i++)
            {
            _param +=param[i] ' ' + param[i + 1];
           IEnumerable<UploadSearch> _viewModel = (from uploads in _db.Uploads
                                                   .Where(p => p.ProcessState_id == Security.APPROVED && p.Finder.Contains(_param))
                                                   .OrderByDescending(p => p.UploadDate)
                                                   select new UploadSearch
                                                   {
                                                       User_id = uploads.User_id,
                                                       UserName = uploads.Users.Name,
                                                       UserLastName = uploads.Users.LastName,
                                                   });
 viewModel = viewModel.Union(_viewModel);                                                   
                                                   }
```

And I use a `Union` clause.

But There has to be another way to do it.

Any Ideas?

Comment: what do you mean by "dynamic" where condition? I'm not sure I understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

You should use LinqKit, it has a PredicateBuilder class that allows you to dynamically build queries

https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit#predicatebuilder

```
IQueryable<Product> SearchProducts (params string[] keywords)
{
  var predicate = PredicateBuilder.New<Product>();

  foreach (string keyword in keywords)
  {
    string temp = keyword;
    predicate = predicate.Or (p => p.Description.Contains (temp));
  }
  return dataContext.Products.Where (predicate);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it is posible to buid queries with combinations? if I have 3 words, can I match those words? 1-2, 1-3, 2-1,2-3,3-2,3-1?